Can we dynamically specify a subnet with more IPs for an AWS Glue job?
I am working on an AWS Glue job and facing issues with IP exhaustion in my current subnet. I need to dynamically specify a subnet with more available IPs when running my Glue job.
Current Setup:
Glue Connections Creation: During stack creation, we create Glue connections as part of the core stack.
Subnet Selection: All connections are selected from a predefined set of subnets.
Connection Objects: The new connection objects are stored in an array.
Glue Job: This array is passed to the Glue job.
Is it possible to configure AWS Glue to select a specific subnet dynamically based on the availability of IPs? If so, how can I achieve this?
I have explored the Glue job parameters and networking configuration options but haven't found a way to make this dynamic. Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Environment:
AWS Glue version: 3.0
Thanks in advance for your help!
